# Angular 7 Routing - How to ensure all routes are prepended with a :gymId parameter

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I've been trying to figure out how to accomplish this where all of my angular routes have a parameter prepended to them.

My routes look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomePageComponent },
  {
    path: ':gymId',
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: UserLoginComponent },
      { path: 'profile', component: UserProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
      {
        path: 'users',
        children: [
          {
            path: ':userId',
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: UserProfileComponent,
                },
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'events',
        children: [
          { path: '', component: EventsListComponent },
          {
            path: ':eventId',
            children: [
                {
                    path: '',
                    component: ViewEventComponent,
                },
                {
                  path: 'edit',
                  component: EventEditorComponent,
                  canActivate: [AuthGuard]
              }
            ]
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        path:'event/new',
        component: EventEditorComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard]
      }
    ]
  },

];
```

Is there a way where if a user attempts to go to a page without the `:gymId`, it will automatically add that? Such as `/profile` -> `/gym151/profile` or if a user just redirects to `/`, it will go to `/gym151`?

Comment: so the user cannot navigate to '/'? It should redirect to '/:gymId/profile'? If that's the case then you could change the HomeComponent route so that the empty route path redirects to the desired route instead. https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects

Comment: hmm how can I get the `:gymId` if it's no longer in the route? I subscribe to the route params for that and if they go to a URL that no longer has it in the route, it breaks everything :/

Answer (score 0):

You might could try a Deactivate guard and redirect to an appropriate route from there.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RedirectGuard implements CanDeactivate<TodoComponent> {
  canDeactivate(
    component: TodoComponent,
    currentRoute: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    currentState: RouterStateSnapshot,
    nextState?: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${currentRoute.params['gymId']}`);
    return true;
  }

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) { }
}
```

Something like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uttust

Comment: This is just very basic so if you go with something like this I'm sure it can be modified to better fit your needs.

Comment: would the `this.router.navigateByUrl(`/${currentRoute.params['gymId']}`);` need additional routes to it or this enough to prepend all routes with that param gymId?

Comment: This would redirect every route this is attached to when you try to navigate away from that component. You would probably want to check the route to see if it needs to be redirected before calling the navigatebyurl

Comment: hmm I'm looking at the Angular docs on CanDeactivate, and I'm not quite sure what the `component` is there for. What's that related to specifically?

Comment: One of the uses of the can deactivate guard is to provide a way to prevent navigation from a component when a form has changed and hasn't been saved. The component gives access to the component so you can check the status of the component if necessary.